# sync database changes between server and multiple clients

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, synchronization

I have a master SQL Server database (hosted online) which syncs and serves data to multiple clients (who in turn work on the same data).  Some clients will be constantly connected to the internet (and can sync immediately to the master), but other clients will have no access to the database for certain periods (up to a few days at a time).
I have a local MS Access database on each machine (which is primarily worked on and which is to be synced back and to with the master when available) and I am wondering how can I sync everything together and not lose any data? Some clients won't be connected for days and might edit the same rows as constantly connected clients, how would I sync when connected to the internet to not lose data between them all?

Because of the incompatibility with MS Access files and the SQL server db, I have planned on bringing all data to DataTables and managing them like that before sending information back to the databases (and because of this it would make sql server change tracking impossible).  I have heard of Microsoft's Sync Framework (but found nothing on it thus far).  I did think about manually storing executed statements locally on the computer and then executing them when connected to the internet (but this could overwrite newer data with older data that never got the chance to be synced).  I am at a loss as to what to do and any help would be appreciated on how I could solve these problems.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Why not storing a Datetime with the data in MsAccess and SQL server ? When the offline client finally get an internet connection, you only sync the MsAccess data having a DateModified date > to Sql Server Data

Answer (score 0):

Not intended as a comprehensive answer, but this was too long for a comment:

The programmer has to come up with sane **merging rules** that work for the type of data and are expected by the user, and has to create his framework to support merging by these rules. There is no Plan X that works well for every piece of data.

Three different value types with an example each, where only the programmer can decide, based on his knowledge of the data.

For example an int: Client A and Client B get the value 1.
It may contain the last value: Client A edits to 4 on Jul 28th, and syncs to server on Aug 2nd. Client B edits to 3 on Jul 29th and syncs on Jul 29th. Which one should the server contain in the end? And what if Client C gets the 3 before Client A syncs, and edits to 7?
Of course it may also be a counter: Client A has added 3 and Client B has added 2, and after both have synced, the server should contain 6.

A date value: Client A edits on Jul 28th and syncs on Aug 2nd, Client B edits on Jul 29th and syncs on Jul 29th. Two simple values that are possible: It could be the LastEditOn field, which should contain the date that Client B set, or the LastSyncOn field, which should contain the date that Client A set.

A text field: Both clients get "Text".
Client A changes to "SomeText" on Jul 28th, and syncs on Aug 2nd.
Client B changes to "TextEtc" on Jul 29th and syncs on Jul 29th.

Depending on your needs, you could merge to:

- TextEtc
- SomeText
- SomeTextEtc
- SomeText
  non-mergeable edit by B: TextEtc
- Text
  EDIT by A: SomeText
  EDIT by B: TextEtc
- Text
  EDIT by B: TextEtc
  EDIT by A: SomeText

to name only a few possibilities.

You see, the programmer is not (yet) superfluous. You have to decide, for every record type and every piece of data, how to merge all the possible changes into a sane new single value. **This is nothing we can do for you, since we do not know what exactly your data is.**

What we can say: You will definitely need a date when the record was last changed. You may also need the dates when certain fields were last changed, or what certain fields contained the last time they were synced with the server.

Where sane merging is not possible, you have to work with a **lock**. A certain client may only change a piece of data when that data is locked on the server. Since clients may walk away in between, your lock should only hold for a certain period of time.